# Pyparsing - recursion returned unexpected results

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-processing, pyparsing

I'm struggling with a basic recursive pyparsing problems.  The first problem is why is it adding an additional tuple layer and the second problem is why is it not breaking apart the `list_pattern` element.

```
def parse_tree_to_dict(data):

    import pyparsing as pp

    _printables = list(pp.printables) + [" "]
    _printables = "".join([x for x in _printables if x not in ["|", "}", "{"]])

    word_pattern = pp.Word(_printables)
    list_pattern = pp.delimitedList(pp.OneOrMore(word_pattern), "|")

    itemlist = pp.dictOf(list_pattern, pp.nestedExpr("{", "}"))
    items = itemlist.parseString(data)

    # print(items.dump())
    print(items.asDict())
    return items.asDict()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    s = "a1{a3|b3}"
    data = parse_tree_to_dict(s)
```

When you run this you get this:

```
{'a1': (['a3|b3'], {})}
```

So where it the tuple coming from, and why isn't the `list_pattern` broke apart - I would have at least expected

```
{'a1': ['a3', 'b3']}
```

The recursion components appear to be working when we add in more complex structures, but the same base problem is coming up.

```
    s = "a1{b2{a3|b3}c2{d3|e3}e2{a4}}b1{a6|b7}"
    data = parse_tree_to_dict(s)
```

This will result in

```
{'a1': (['b2', (['a3|b3'], {}), 'c2', (['d3|e3'], {}), 'e2', (['a4'], {})], {}), 'b1': (['a6|b7'], {})}
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks for looking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of expressions that are stepping on each other. You take a stab at defining a list_pattern for your dict values, but then when you define the dictOf, you use the list_pattern for the key and the generic nestedExpr for the value.  nestedExpr isn't going to do anything special with the '|' delimiters, it is just going to work off of the '{' '}' nesting characters and give you lists of the printable words within them. Since 'a3|b3' has no spaces, nestedExpr is just going to return it as one word.

It looks to me like your dict is composed of keys that a single words, followed by a possibly nested subdict. Here is a first step toward getting that going (I don't think this will completely get you the nested dict output, but its a start):

```
list_pattern = pp.Forward()
LBR,RBR = map(pp.Suppress,"{}")
list_pattern << pp.delimitedList(pp.OneOrMore(word_pattern|pp.Group(LBR+list_pattern+RBR)), "|")

itemlist = pp.dictOf(word_pattern, list_pattern)
```

This will parse out your data and give you the list of values for 'a3' and 'b3'.

```
{'a1': (['a3', 'b3'], {})}
```

The second part of your question is "where does that tuple come from?" Well, there *is* no tuple, what you are seeing is the full repr output for pyparsing's ParseResults type. Since ParseResults serves a dual interface of both a list of parsed tokens and named results, its repr is a tuple of the tokens and a dict of the results names.

You can see this a little more clearly if we try to access the first item's value by its key:

```
print data.keys()[0]
print data[data.keys()[0]]  # or print data['a1']
```

prints

```
a1
['a3', 'b3']
```

You can always collapse a ParseResults down to an actual list using asList().

Also, look into the new constructor argument for the Word class, excludeChars. It makes it much easier to define a Word using all the characters in printables *except* for a few to be excluded.

Comment: You as always nailed it!!